# React sidebar menu

Tags: reactjs, menu, sidebar

I am new in react so sorry if the question sounds silly!
I am trying to make a sidebar menu with vertical tabs like the picture below but i can't find anything on how to make the side-tabs open this way (vertically) .
More specifically I want i sidebar like this when it is closed [closed sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJpGV.png)
and then when i open it to expand each tab vertically with info
[sidebar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPfLY.png)
[sidebar example clicking on other tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXoep.png)

Thank you

Comment: you can use https://mui.com/ they have pretty much every component you need, there is no perfect component, so you will need to modify pre-built components or create one from scratch.

Comment: ok thank you! I will check it out